# 2010: How to get rid of the bottom Cancel button (not the close X Button) in a modal dialog page which uses dialog.master as Master Page?

Tags: 2010, modal-dialog

My custom dialog page uses dialog.master as master page.
It shows a Cancel button at the **bottom right** of the dialog box, which closes the dialog instantly.

Since I implemented my own cancel button which does some stuff in the OnClick event, I do not need the default one. How can I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a property in Dialog options

`showClose
boolean (true/false)
Determines the visibility of the close button (at top right corner) for the modal dialog`

To use it:

```
var options = { 
url: '/SitePages/Page.aspx', 
title: 'Page Title', 
allowMaximize: false, 
showClose: false, 
width: 800, 
height: 600, 
dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseCallback }; 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Reference:

[SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058%28office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: The "Close" Button is not the "Cancel" button I'm talking of